# object is possibly "undefined" ts2532

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the error when I want to make a slider and I have looked for several alternatives to solve it but none of them work. The error is in useEffect(() => {setWidth ( carousel.current.scrollWidth - carousel.current.offsetWidth)}, []); and in carousel.current

```js
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import images from "../images";

function Sliders() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const carousel = useRef();

  
  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth (carousel.current.scrollWidth -  carousel.current.offsetWidth)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Sliders">
      <motion.div red={carousel} className="carusel" whileTap={{cursor: "grabbing"}} >
        <motion.div drag="x"
          dragConstraints={{ right: 0, left: -width}}
          className="inner-carousel"
        >
          {images.map((image) => {
            return (
              <motion.div className="item" key={image}>
                <img src={image} alt="" />
              </motion.div>
            );
          })}
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sliders
```

Comment: `carousel.current` might be undefined. You have to check that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

When the component is launched, initially the value for `carousel.current` is undefined. Just wrap the statement in if condition, and I believe it should work.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (carousel?.current) {
    setWidth (carousel.current.scrollWidth -  carousel.current.offsetWidth)
  }
}, []);
```

Note: You can try to console carousel.current before return statement to be sure when the object is undefined and at what point it gets populated.